# OpenSnitch for device ports

Tags: usb, security

From the OpenSnitch GitHub page:

> **OpenSnitch** is a GNU/Linux port of the Little Snitch application firewall.
>
> [Here is an image of it in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zINcr.png)

Is there something that works like it but for device ports like USB, Thunderbolt or HDMI?

Answer (score 1):

There's the usbguard and usbauth packages for USB ports.

There's the bolt and thunderbolt-tools packages for thunderbolt ports.

I know of nothing similar for HDMI.